# Python list to list

Tags: python

I want to equal to a[0]=recv_pak[0], a[1]=recv_pac[1]... until a[4]. recv_pack list has 20 arguments but i want to chose just first 4 arguments. I am using this code lines but i have `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

error how can i solve ?

```
while 1:
   # sock.send(req)
    #print("TX: (%s)" % repr(req))
    rec = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print("RX: (%s)" % repr(rec))
    time.sleep(2)
    break



 print("\nSwitching Plug OFF...")

    recv_pack=struct.unpack('12B',rec)
    print(recv_pack)

    a=[]
    for i in range(0,4):
        a[i]=recv_pack[i]
        print(a[i])
```

Comment: Please double-check your indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `list.append`

**Ex:**

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    a.append(recv_pack[i])
    print(a[i])
```

---

You can also use list `slicing`

**Ex:**

```
a = recv_pack[:4]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

'a' is an empty list, but you're attempting to write to element [0] in the first iteration, which doesn't exist yet.

Try the following instead, to add a new element to the end of the list:

`for i in range(0,4):
    a.append(recv_pack[i])
    print(a[i])`

Answer (score 0):

And now for the simple pythonic version:

```
a = recv_pack[:4]
```

which means: "gimme a list of the four first items in `recv_pack` and bind it to name 'a'"